# Remove sort order from table header in Interface Builder?

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I accidentally clicked on the header of an `NSTableView` in Interface Builder (Xcode 4.3.2), which caused the header to get highlighted and display a search order indicator for a certain column. I only noticed this after I had already saved and reopened the xib file, so I can't undo it anymore.

Because of this, the `NSTableView` already has a sort order when my application launches, but I want to leave it to the user to decided whether he wants the table view sorted or not.

How can I undo this change in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still on IB 3.2.6, but here it works to temporarily remove the Sort Key from the table column. You can restore it afterward.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I wonder if there is a way for my application's users to remove sorting other than restarting the application …